# Является ли первое высказывание первого участника диалога репликой?

Tags: грамотная-речь, значение-слов

В уроках русского языка часто можно встретить такое утверждение:

> «Реплика — каждое отдельное высказывание лиц, принимающих участие в
> диалоге».
>  [[yaklass.ru](https://www.yaklass.ru/p/russky-yazik/5-klass/osnovnye-poniatiia-sintaksisa-i-punktuatcii-10910/priamaia-rech-dialog-11543/re-28e16e7e-08c2-41dd-8afd-9b4d67847ee7)]

Это цитата из урока «2. Диалог» цифрового образовательного ресурса [ЯКласс](https://www.yaklass.ru/p/russky-yazik/5-klass/osnovnye-poniatiia-sintaksisa-i-punktuatcii-10910/priamaia-rech-dialog-11543/re-28e16e7e-08c2-41dd-8afd-9b4d67847ee7).

То есть репликой считается **каждое** высказывание.

Далее в этом же уроке идёт такой текст:

> Если слова автора стоят перед репликой, то после них ставится
> двоеточие.
>
> *Пример:*
>
> *«Вовка подошёл к комоду, нагнулся, хотел поднять шляпу — и вдруг как
> закричит:
> — Ай-ай-ай! — и бегом в сторону.
> — Чего ты? — спрашивает
> Вадик»
> (Н. Носов).*

Из этого текста следует, что авторы рассматривают первое высказывание «Ай-ай-ай!» как реплику.

---

И это не единичный случай, во всех, найденных мной, обучающих текстах по русскому языку, все высказывания диалога рассматриваются как реплики; в том числе первое.

---

Однако такое понимание реплики противоречит её словарным определениям и этимологии.

Для примера можно взять толковый словарь Ушакова:

> **ре́плика**...
>
> 1. Ответ, возражение, замечание одного собеседника на слова другого. *Подавать реплику.*
> 2. Последние слова одного актера, вслед за к-рыми другой актер произносит следующие по ходу пьесы слова (театр.). *Выписывать реплики.*
> 3. Краткий возглас, возражение или замечание с места по содержанию речи оратора. *Посыпались реплики.*
> 4. Возражение стороны на судебном процессе (право). *Р. обвинителя.*
> 5. Повторение музыкальной фразы в другой тональности (муз.).

Из пяти определений подходит первое. Второе, четвёртое и пятое — специальные определения: театральное, правовое и музыкальное. Третье касается замечаний по речи оратора.

Итак, первое определение:

> 1. Ответ, возражение, замечание одного собеседника на слова другого.

Таким образом, реплика — это, по сути, ответ на слова другого человека, но ни как не слова, сказанные первым участником беседы.

И это не единственный словарь, который даёт такое определение.

---

Таким образом, в диалоге:

> — Ай-ай-ай! — и бегом в сторону.
> — Чего ты? — спрашивает Вадик.

Репликой является только «Чего ты?»,  а «Ай-ай-ай!» репликой не является.

---

Если рассмотреть этимологию слова «реплика»:

> Происходит от итал. replica «возражение; повторение», от гл. replicare
> «возражать; повторять», далее из лат. replicare «разворачивать,
> отгибать; отражать; возражать», далее из re- «обратно; опять, снова;
> против», далее из неустановленной формы + plicāre «складывать,
> свёртывать» (восходит к праиндоевр. *plek- «плести, скручивать»).
> [[Викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)]

С этимологической точки зрения реплика так же является ответом (возражением) на слова другого, но никак не словами того, кто говорит первым.

---

Если подытожить:

Исходя из определения в русских словарях и исходя из этимологии: реплика —  это то, что говорится в ответ на чьи-то слова.

Однако создатели учебных материалов по русскому языку упорно называют репликой — «**каждое** отдельное высказывание лиц, принимающих участие в диалоге».

Получается, в том числе и первое высказывание, а не начиная со второго.

Правильно ли это и на чём это основано?

Answer (score 1):

Термин "реплика" связан в первую очередь с театром. В учебнике по теории драмы Чистюхина реплика - это "факт ответа на предшествующий дискурс или немедленное парирование аргумента". Речевая ситуация - вполне себе дискурс, на который можно отреагировать репликой.
Первое высказывание, открывающее диалог, называется реплика-стимул. Вот объяснение термина из словаря лингвистических терминов Жеребило Т.В.: Реплика, открывающая диалогическое единство, определяющая содержание и форму следующего за ним высказывания.
Р.-с. представляет собой независимый речевой акт:

1. вопрос, требующий ответа;
2. побуждение к действию;
3. высказывание, инициирующее тему, нуждающееся в уточнении или пояснении, экспрессив (речевой акт, выражающий эмоции говорящего).

Comment: Надежда, спасибо за ответ. Я за него проголосовал, потому что вижу, что вы приложили усилия. Однако ясности для меня не наступило. С одной стороны: *«реплика — это факт ответа на предшествующий дискурс или немедленное парирование аргумента»*. Откуда следует, что первое высказывание всё-таки не реплика. А потом говорится, что первое высказывание — это реплика-стимул. В этом есть какое-то противоречие. И почему вообще «реплика» рассматривается в школьной программе, если это сугубо специализированный театральный термин. В профессиональной среде значения слов могут отличиться от общепринятых.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что определение через "каждое" (= всякое) *неверно*: *первое* обращение к собеседнику не может быть репликой (этимология слова не настолько забыта, чтобы её игнорировать, - это прежде всего "ответ").

Однако "Ай-ай-ай" здесь - не обращение к собеседнику, а *ответная реакция* на внешнюю неожиданность, поэтому условно можно и *репликой* назвать. Вряд ли можно было в словарных обобщениях (они не предназначены для конструирования речи) учесть и это, но этимологическому смыслу такая трактовка *не* противоречит.

Comment: Реплика произносится в ответ на слова другого, а не как реакция на ползущую шляпу. «Ай-ай-ай!» — в данном случае просто высказывание, выражающее эмоцию испуга.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ. Однако это скорее ваше мнение. И хотя мне было интересно его услышать, и несмотря на то, что разделяю вашу точку зрения, что первое высказывание не реплика, я хотел бы получить более точный ответ с какими-то фактами, на которые можно опереться.